# How do I cast DWORD to PVOID in c++?

Tags: c++, casting

This is the definition of my function where I try to cast dwAddress, which is a DWORD, to a void pointer with reinterpret_cast(dwAddress):

```
template <class T>
    inline bool Read(DWORD dwAddress, T& Value){

        return ReadProcessMemory(m_HProcess, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(dwAddress), Value, sizeof(T), NULL) == true;
    }
```

This is where I call the function:

```
DWORD testValue = 1;
        if(MemoryManager->Read<DWORD>(dwClientBase+dwForceAttack,testValue))
```

And this is my error:

```
C:\Users\...\CLionProjects\...\CMemoryManager.h: In instantiation of 'bool CMemoryManager::Read(DWORD, T&) [with T = long unsigned int; DWORD = long unsigned int]':
C:\Users\...\CLionProjects\...\main.cpp:23:75:   required from here
C:\Users\...\CLionProjects\...\CMemoryManager.h:28:33: error: invalid conversion from 'long unsigned int' to 'PVOID' {aka 'void*'} [-fpermissive]
         return ReadProcessMemory(m_HProcess, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(dwAddress), Value, sizeof(T), NULL) == true;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\...\CLionProjects\...\CMemoryManager.h:7,
                 from C:\Users\...\CLionProjects\...\main.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:2260:59: note:   initializing argument 3 of 'BOOL ReadProcessMemory(HANDLE, PCVOID, PVOID, DWORD, PDWORD)'
 WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI ReadProcessMemory (HANDLE, PCVOID, PVOID, DWORD, PDWORD);
```

I dont get why the cast wont work. I already tried a lot of different casting methods but nothing would work.

Comment: The issue seems to be with `Value` not `dwAddress`

Comment: Note that `DWORD` is only 32 bits.  So this won'r work on 64 bit systems

Comment: Oh wow you are right.... thaank you

Comment: Remember; a cast just tells the compiler to treat some type as some other type. It doesn't magically *convert* one type into another.

Comment: Thank you guys... I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also cast `Value`, the third argument in your ReadProcessMemory call.

```
reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(Value)
```

Keep in mind you must compile for the same architecture as the target process, if your target is x64 you must also be x64.